# Editing file command within sh script with expressions

Tags: linux, shell, ubuntu, ssh

I am currently trying to write a shell script, which will take two user defined variables ($uname and $dname) and add as a line in /etc/rc.local.

It must create a new line after the the **begin** line each time it is run.

I am using sed for this, but cannot seem to work out the best way to insert these variables within the script, currently I have this but it's throwing out "Syntax error: Unterminated quoted string":

```
sed  '/\begin\/ mount --bind /var/www/'"$dname"'/htdocs /home/'"$uname"'/'"$dname"'/htdocs' /etc/rc.local
```

I would also like to have a script that finds and deletes this line from this file, based on the $dname.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: **Warning:** If two users (`$uname`) have equal `$dname`, you might get unexpected behavior.

Comment: **Tip:** `sed` allows using another char than `/` for splitting the regex. When using paths, I'd recommend using `#` instead, so you don't need to scape the path splitting char with `\/`: `sed 's#...#...#'`

Comment: **Error:** You need to tell `sed` the action to perform. As you want to replace strings, you need to add an `s` at the beginning of your regex (just before the splitting char): `sed 's...'`

Comment: **Tip:** To replace strings in a file and save the results in the same file, you need to add the `sed` option `-i` or `--in-place`: `sed 's#...#...#' -i /etc/rc.local`

Comment: **Tip:** Instead of using a single mutable script for all mounts, I'd recommend having a single unmutable script calling all unmutuable scripts present in a folder. Then, you create (maybe using a template and/or a `sed` command) or remove files, instead of modifying them. This will be much easier to maintain. You can use `run-parts` to run all scripts in a folder.